# In Digimon Adventure, Koushiro/Izzy is revealed to be adopted. Why was he adopted in the first place?

Tags: digimon

Was it because his birth parents died, or was it because the biological child of his adopted parents died?

Comment: "*Izzy's real father was a genius mathematician. He and his wife died in a car crash when he was a baby.*" - Per the wiki

Comment: "*He was adopted by Izumi Masami, a distant relative of his father's and his wife Kae, who had suffered the loss of their own baby boy not long before the accident.*"

Comment: Or both? It is a fun story for kids, after all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The various Wikis, though largely unsourced or not cited, are correct when saying Izzy's parents died and he was adopted by Izumi Masami and his wife Kae after they lost their son.

In [*Digimon Adventures*, Episode 38 "Prophecy"](https://digimon.fandom.com/wiki/Prophecy) at around 7:20, Izumi Masami tells Izzy about his real father, and what happened to his parents:

> *Izzy*: What was my real father like?
>
> *Izumi Masami*: He was a fine man and a brilliant mathematician. In fact, he was a lecturer at the university. He and I were distant cousins. I was his only living relative, and your mother had no family of her own so... when it happened... Late one night there was a terrible car accident, **neither of them survived**.
>
> *Izumi Kae*: **We had lost a little boy of our own** you see, just before. So, when we were asked if we might want to take care of you... Well, it seemed like, I don't know, some kind of sign. We said yes.